# Mysqldump taking too much time

Tags: mysql, mysqldumpslow

MySQLdump and upload process taking too long time (~8 hr) to complete the whole process.

I am dumping active database into mysqldump.tar file and almost 3gb. When I load into new database its taking 6-8 hr to complete the process (upload into new database).

What will be the recommended solution for me to complete the process?

Comment: [See here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database).

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming questions. This falls under administration, so try http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, your main problem is that loading the data into your new database is the step that's taking a lot of time. Besides reading the link provided by asdf in his comment (["How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database?"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database)), I suggest you some things:

- Use the `--disable-keys` option; this will add `alter table your_table DISABLE KEYS` before the inserts, and `alter table your_table ENABLE KEYS` after the inserts are done. When I've used this option, the insertion time is about 30% faster
- If possible, use the `--delayed-insert` option; whis will use `INSERT DELAYED` insted of the "normal" `INSERT`.
- If possible, dump the data of different tables into different files; that way you may upload them concurrently.

[Check the reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) for further information.